# How to make CCMenuItemImage call the selector on touch press (instead of touch release)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

A CCMenuItemImage will call the selector after the touch that was pressing it releases it.

However, is it not possible to make it call the selector *as soon as the touch presses it?* This is to create a faster effect in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subclass CCMenuItemImage and process the event

```
-(void) selected{
    // do you thing : for example you could have a target:selector pair of 
    // properties added in your implementation.
    [super selected];
}
```

i use that to detect a long touch and pop a contextual tooltip window (for example).